# Difficult integration problem (unique headline)

Tags: integration

So I found this difficult integral at Physicsforum (I'm quite sure you are familiar with this forum) and I've been at it for about an hour now and it's quite frustrating because I can't get the answer.

$$\int \frac{4x^5 -1}{x^5 + x +1} dx $$

I would really love it if someone could help me with this

Comment: Is it supposed to be an indefinite integral? Because the result cannot be expressed nicely, namely it is $$4 x-\sqrt{3} \text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{1+2 x}{\sqrt{3}}\right]-\frac{1}{2} \text{Log}\left[1+x+x^2\right]+\text{RootSum}\left[1-\text{$\#$1}^2+\text{$\#$1}^3\&,\frac{-3 \text{Log}[x-\text{$\#$1}]+\text{Log}[x-\text{$\#$1}] \text{$\#$1}^2}{-2 \text{$\#$1}+3 \text{$\#$1}^2}\&\right]$$; here the RootSum function has to do with the roots of the denominator; because there is no general formula for the roots of a 5th degree polynomial, the result is not beautiful.

Comment: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%284x^5-1%29%2F%28x^5%2Bx%2B1%29) is probably why you're having trouble. The answer is quite ugly, and cannot be expressed easily.

Comment: You most likely misstyped the question, see problem 48 on page 68 here http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/Integral%20Kokeboken.pdf

Comment: Looks like you are using mathematica because of the # symbols (which are non sense) and the capitalization of your functions

Comment: This integral might be way to difficult for me to even have begun now that i look at your answer

Comment: If you replace the denominator by its square, the result is very simple, as WolframAlpha shows.

Comment: @Squirtle It isn't "nonsense."  It is just a shorthand notation for a much more complicated expression.  Specifically, the `Rootsum[]` expression is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{(r_i^2 - 3)\log(x-r_i)}{(3r_i-2)r_i},$$ where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are the distinct roots of $z^3-z^2+1=0$.  Since two of these roots are complex conjugates, it is difficult to write this expression in terms of real values.

Answer (score -1):

Taking the question as it is, it is a rational function and therefore cen be integrated by partial fractions. Fist divide the denominator into the numerator to get a fraction where the numerator has a smaller degree. Integrating the quotient gives $4x$. Now the problem is to factor the denominator. However it does not have any rational roots. It is of odd degree so has at least one real root, so irrational quantities will be an essential part of the answer. The other question is how many factors are linear and how many complex. You can work this out by graphing the function (maxima and minima).
Each linear factor gives a logarithm and each quadratic a inverse tangent. So you should be able to determine the general form of the integral, but not the specific constants involved.